# How to change root password for mysql and phpmyadmin-mint Linux

Tags: linux-mint, mysql, php, phpmyadmin

I have recently installed Linux Mint. I have installed

1) Lamp

2) Set up MySQL

3) Test Apache

4) Test PHP

5) Phpmyadmin

Everything was working fine. Unfortunately my password include $ character.

Then I discovered that characters `?{}|&~![()^"` must not be used
anywhere in the key and have a special meaning in the value.
I tried `SET PASSWORD FOR root@localhost = PASSWORD('yourpassword');` but it's not working. So how can I change the root password for MySQL and phpmyadmin?

Comment: Which "root password" has the `$` in it that you need to change?

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver both Mysql and phpmyadmin are same.if i use parse_ini_file its not connected to db.please helpme

Answer (score 2):

You need to do this:

1. Stop the MySQL server
2. Restart the MySQL server skipping the grant tables: 
   `mysqld_safe --skip-grant-tables --skip-networking &`
3. Connect to the MySQL server passwordlessly: `mysql -uroot`
4. Reload the grant tables: `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;`
5. Change the root password: `SET PASSWORD FOR 'root'@'localhost' = PASSWORD('hello');`
6. Stop the MySQL server and restart it normally
7. You can now connect to MySQL as root with password `hello`

Concerning phpMyAdmin, it uses MySQL credentials. So once you have regained MySQL's root password, you'll be able to manage everything.

Comment: @dr01-same for phpmyadmin?

Comment: phpMyAdmin uses MySQL credentials. Once you have regained MySQL's root password, you'll be able to manage everything.

Comment: @dr01 Point number 2 does not work on Linux Mint Tessa.